# Running 32bit Orwell Dev-C++ on 32bit Win8 with 64bit CPU - incerementing pointer returns incorrect result

Tags: c++, pointers, gcc, dev-c++, pointer-arithmetic

I have the following small piece of code that works without any issues on a 64bit Debian 7:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int s = 10;
  int q = 100;
  int *myPtr = &s;

  cout << "s = " << s
       << "\n&s = " << &s
       << "\nq = " << q
       << "\n&q = " << &q
       << "\nmyPtr = " << myPtr
       << "\n&myPtr = " << &myPtr
       << "\n*myPtr = " << *myPtr
       << endl;

  myPtr = myPtr + 1; // Go one

  cout << "myPtr = " << myPtr
       << "\n&myPtr = " << &myPtr
       << "\n*myPtr = " << *myPtr << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

A colleague executed this very same code and got totally different result after the increment of the pointer **myPtr**. His computer is a 32bit Windows 8 on a 64bit processor.
On Win8 we are using the the TDM-GCC 4.8.1 32bit release integrated in Orwell Dev-C++ latest version. On Linux we have GCC 4.7 multiplatform (project in CMake does not specify architecture so I presume the compiled file is 64bit).

I got

```
myPtr = <address of q>
&myPtr = <address of myPtr; same as before>
*myPtr = 100
```

but he go

```
myPtr = <NOT address of q>
&myPtr = <address of myPtr; same as before>
*myPtr = 4096
```

I am completely baffled by this behaviour. I though I got the pointer arithmetic wrong but I did check online even though I'm pretty sure there is nothing wrong with it (I'll feel stupid if that's not the case :D). I simply tell **myPtr** to point to the next block with size of an integer (since the pointer is of type integer), which in my case is **q**.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Unrelated: `char **argv[]` isn't correct for the second parameter to `main`, it should be either `char *argv[]` or `char **argv`, not both. In practice it shouldn't be there at all, as it isn't even used: `int main()`

Comment: Your increment of `myPtr` is illegal.

Comment: @WhozCraig, yes, I just saw that. I added copied my char** argv but was writing here while talking about array with a colleague of mine so I added it. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking undefined behavior. Your pointer is a pointer to `s`.

When you increment it, you are pointing to memory that you did not allocate. The address of the pointer itself did not change obviously, but the memory address it is pointing at did.

Deferencing that pointer after that just interprets whatever value happens to be at that address as an `int`. And as I just said, since you did not allocate that memory, it is undefined behavior.

Comment: Nitpick: dereferencing the incremented `myPtr` invokes undefined behavior immediately. It doesn't necessarily "interpret whatever value happens to be at that address as an int" - some implementations may choose to do that, others may behave differently (e.g. by crashing or [time travelling](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/06/27/10537746.aspx)).

Comment: Awww, you are right...It's not a sequence of allocated memory blocks so the q might be way off. I forgot about the fact that this kind of arithmetic can be applied on a sequential memory block such as arrays and structures. Thanks!

Comment: @rbaleksandar Oh okay I understand your confusion. You initially thought that `s` and `q` would be allocated memory right next to each other? That may happen (if you are lucky) but it is completely up to the compiler and would not depend on that, as it is unlikely.

Comment: Yeah, I totally forgot about that. And it was a HUGE coincidence that in my Linux case it actually returned the next integer variable. LOL Bad luck I guess. :D After you posted your comment I added another variable after that in order to get what you meant and it was then obvious how foolish I was. -_-